# How to exclude an unused case by conditions

Tags: ruby, if-statement, coding-style, conditional-statements, conventions

Which is better?

```
string.each_char do |letter|
    unless letter == " "
        if letters.has_key?(letter)
            letters[letter] = letters[letter].next
        else
            letters[letter] = 1
        end
    end
end
```

or

```
string.each_char do |letter|
    if letter == " "
    elsif letters.has_key?(letter)
        letters[letter] = letters[letter].next
    else
        letters[letter] = 1
    end
end
```

It seems awkward to leave an if statement without the body, but it also seems preferable to going a step deeper with unless.

There's a better way to write this code. I didn't know about default Hash values, and that would clean this code up a lot, but I still wanted to know which is preferable: an if statement without body, or unless, or something else.

Comment: It's a matter of taste I think, but if I have to choose out of these two options, I'm with you here: I like the second, less nested variant more. But if I didn't have to choose, I'd go with the solution based on Hash default value (like you mentioned), or even more functional approach: `letters = string.chars.group_by(&:itself).map{|ch,dupes| [ch, dupes.size]}.to_h` (it only works on most recent Ruby versions; Array#to_h and Object#itself are relatively new additions).

Comment: Less nesting is very strong improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the nicest:

```
letters = Hash.new(0)
string = "aaabbc"
string.each_char do |letter|
    if letter != " "
        letters[letter] += 1
    end
end
# => {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}
```

For deciding between your two examples, I would avoid adding extra-depth (more indentation). The second one is also easier to read because it's simple to follow a string of `if/else` statements. It's almost always preferable to have more readable code than fancy code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value for a hash when constructing:

```
letters = Hash.new(0)
...
letters[letter] = letters[letter].next
```

An interesting approach using this is to use some of the map / reduce methods offered by Ruby:

```
letters = string.chars
  .reject{ |letter| letter == " " }
  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |letter, memo| 
    memo[letter] = memo[letter].next
  }
```